# CakePHP 3.x - AuthComponent::user() in View

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2.x you could do

```
 AuthComponent::user()
```

in View to get data from Auth component. In CakePHP 3.0beta3 it throws:

```
 "Error: Class 'AuthComponent' not found"
```

Is there a simple way to get data from AuthComponent in View?

Comment: It is documented in the book here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Cake 3.5**

In *AppController*:

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event) {
    ....

    $this->set('Auth', $this->components()->__get('Auth'));
}
```

In *.ctp* template:

```
<?php if (!$Auth->user()) { ?>
    <a class="login" href="<?php echo $this->Url->build($Auth->getConfig('loginAction')); ?>">Login</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="name"><?php echo h($Auth->user('name')); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Or just [this component and helper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth/blob/master/docs/Authorization.md#authusercomponent).

Answer (score 18):

In View:

```
$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.username');
```

In Controller

```
$this->Auth->user('username');
```

Answer (score 10):

You should have never used the AuthComponent in views in the first place.
It is better to either pass down the data from the controller to the view and access that, or better yet, use a AuthHelper to wrapper-access it easily (by reading from the session there for example).

An example would be `AuthUser` (
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/src/View/Helper/AuthUserHelper.php ):

```
$this->AuthUser->id();
$this->AuthUser->user('username');
```

etc

The helper way doesn't require additional use statements in your view ctps and keeps them lean.
It also prevents notices when trying to access undefined indexed automatically.

```
if ($this->AuthUser->user('foobarbaz')) { // no error thrown even if it never existed
}
```

Comment: The official documentation tells to use the `AuthComponent` static function. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user

Comment: You are misreading that line. It just points out the "method name", the actual example below shows how it is actually done, and that is not statically!

Comment: True, i've seen the function isn't a static one anymore anyway. the documentation seems not to be updated yet. I replace `AuthComponent::user('` with `$this->request->Session()->read('Auth.User.`in all view files to get it working again.

Comment: Again: Where should the documentation not be updated yet? I can't see any usage as static one. All examples, including `$this->Auth->user('id');` are as they should be..

Comment: In the 3.0 documentation http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user is written `You can access the currently logged in user using AuthComponent::user()`.

Comment: Again, that (`ClassName::methodName()`) is the syntax how one tells you the *method and class name*, this is **NOT how you should access it**. The example **below** shows you **how** to access it. That should be totally clear, and is to everyone else. Why else would there be an example following directly afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

The AuthComponent [is deprecated as of 4.0.0](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html) and will be replaced by the [authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/authorization/1.1/en/index.html) and [authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/index.html) plugins.

Authentication plugin has built in [**View Helper**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/view-helper.html).